# Angular: order list by data-order using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular

I have list of boxes which i load  from DB. I am trying to make an ordering function which orders boxes by `data-order`, it should be triggered when user clicks the button.

**Component**

```
 import { JQ_TOKEN} from "../../_service/index";
 constructor( @Inject(JQ_TOKEN) private $: any ) {}
```

**Order Function**

```
orderGames() {
    var boxList = this.$('.box');
    var container = this.$('.box-list-container');
    boxList.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
        return this.$(a).data("order") - this.$(b).data("order");
    });
    container.html(boxList);
}
```

I receive next the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in app/dark-navbar.component.html:44:24 caused by: Cannot read property '$' of undefined

How can I make it work?

Comment: Check that `this` is. My guess is that it's not the class component..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be needing `this`. Here's how I use jQuery in conjunction with Angular:

```
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'some-thing',
  templateUrl: './template.html'
})

export class ApplicationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public results: String[] = [];

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('#offcanvas').click(() => $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active'));
  }
}
```

Comment: When i remove `this`, it says "Cannot find name '$'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.$'"?. There is a problem with `sort(function(a,b)`, if i comment it out, and `log(boxList)` it shows array of div's

Comment: are you bringing in jQuery to your code somehow? Either via a <script> statement or by packaging it up using webpack

Comment: It difficult to explain since that part was done by another people, I just call jQuety with a service

Comment: does this.$ return anything?

Comment: Yes, i use it in another component for `this.$('...').slideToggle()`

Comment: Just check what console.log(this); and console.log(this.$); returns in the component that gives you the error

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't work with angular before .. but as a jquery function you can use something like

```
orderGames(el) {
    var boxList = $(el).find('.box');
    var container = $(el).find('.box-list-container');
    boxList.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).data("order") - $(b).data("order");
    });
    container.html(boxList);
}
```

and use it like

```
orderGames(this)
```

> **Note:** `.find()` *Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.*.. and while I don't know your structure I can't determine which jquery function you
>   will need may be `.find()` , `.prev()` , `.closest()` .. etc